# finding distribution for count data

Tags: count, distribution, data-fitting

I have a problem in finding a proper distribution for my data. the data is count data and ranges between 1 and 205, has a long and thin tail. this is a histogram of my data:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rbqU.jpg)

after some search, I've found that square root transformation can make data fit to poison distribution. after transformation, data ranges between 1 and about 14.5. but still doesn't fit to any distribution. histogram of transformed data looks like below:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFFzu.jpg)

is there any way that I can find a proper transformation or a distribution for this data? I use R language and used `fitdistr` and `ks.test` functions.

Comment: There's no programming content to your question, so this is a poor fit for stackoverflow. I've voted to close the question here.  I think you'd do better to migrate this to [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Exponential perhaps?

Comment: Or if you need it for integers, then there is something like exponential - geometric distribution

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I tried both exponential and geometric with `fitdistr` function and tested with `ks.test`. none of them were significant. are these functions ok for fitting and testing distributions?

Comment: Possibly a discrete gamma with shape parameter < 1?

Comment: Are we going to guess distribution functions from two poor graphs? Try to show some "bad" fits with functions you've tried. Provide the data. Give us some background as where the data is from.